# Pandas: Transferring column values to separate columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiple-columns, pandas-loc

Relatively new to Python here. I have a dataframe with three columns: Teams, Year and Medals_Won like so:

```
Teams   Year    Medals_Won
A       2009    Gold
A       2010    Silver
A       2011    Silver
A       2012    Bronze
A       2013    Gold
B       2009    Bronze
B       2010    Gold
B       2011    Bronze
B       2012    Silver
B       2013    Silver
C       2009    Silver
C       2010    Bronze
C       2011    Gold
C       2012    Gold
C       2013    Bronze
```

I want to take the Medals_Won column and split it based on the type of medals without upsetting the size and order of the first two columns like so (Missing values would be Null/NaN):

```
Teams   Year    Gold_Winner  Silver_Winner  Bronze_Winner
A       2009    Gold         Null           Null
A       2010    Null         Silver         Null
A       2011    Null         Silver         Null
A       2012    Null         Null           Bronze
A       2013    Gold         Null           Null
B       2009    Null         Null           Bronze
B       2010    Gold         Null           Null
B       2011    Null         Null           Bronze
B       2012    Null         Silver         Null
B       2013    Null         Silver         Null
C       2009    Null         Silver         Null
C       2010    Null         Null           Bronze
C       2011    Gold         Null           Null
C       2012    Gold         Null           Null
C       2013    Null         Null           Bronze
```

Can someone please help me in solving this problem? I tried to use the insert function with .loc (which did not work):

```
df.insert(2, 'Gold_Won', df.loc[df[Medals_Won] == 'Gold')
df.insert(3, 'Silver_Won', df.loc[df[Medals_Won] == 'Silver')
df.insert(4, 'Silver_Won', df.loc[df[Medals_Won] == 'Bronze')
```

Answer (score 1):

here is one way to do it

```
# get the dummy columns in a separate DF
dmy=pd.get_dummies(df['Medals_Won'])

# replace values with the column names

dmy=dmy.mul(dmy.columns).replace('','Null')

# combine the two DF
pd.concat([df, dmy],
          axis=1
         )
```

```
Teams   Year    Medals_Won  Bronze  Gold    Silver
0   A   2009    Gold    Null    Gold    Null
1   A   2010    Silver  Null    Null    Silver
2   A   2011    Silver  Null    Null    Silver
3   A   2012    Bronze  Bronze  Null    Null
4   A   2013    Gold    Null    Gold    Null
5   B   2009    Bronze  Bronze  Null    Null
6   B   2010    Gold    Null    Gold    Null
7   B   2011    Bronze  Bronze  Null    Null
8   B   2012    Silver  Null    Null    Silver
9   B   2013    Silver  Null    Null    Silver
10  C   2009    Silver  Null    Null    Silver
11  C   2010    Bronze  Bronze  Null    Null
12  C   2011    Gold    Null    Gold    Null
13  C   2012    Gold    Null    Gold    Null
14  C   2013    Bronze  Bronze  Null    Null
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this two ways

```
df['Gold_Winner'] = None
df.loc[df.Medals_Won == 'Gold', 'Gold_Winner'] = 'Gold'
```

you can iterate

```
 for medal_type in ['Gold', 'Silver', 'Bronze']:
    df[f'{medal_type}_Winner'] = None
    df.loc[df.Medals_Won == medal_type, f'{medal_type}_Winner'] = medal_type
```

a better way is to use pivot

```
df.pivot(index=['Teams', 'Year'], columns='Medals_Won', values='Medals_Won')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you have the dataframe loaded in as `df`, then I think the following code should get you what you're looking for:

```
df["Gold_Winner"] = df["Medals_Won"].apply(lambda x: "Gold" if x == "Gold" else None)
df["Silver_Winner"] = df["Medals_Won"].apply(lambda x: "Silver" if x == "Silver" else None)
df["Bronze_Winner"] = df["Medals_Won"].apply(lambda x: "Bronze" if x == "Bronze" else None)
df = df.drop(columns=["Medals_Won"])
```

It creates one column for each of the gold, silver, and bronze categories and then it drops the `Medals_Won` category.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, there are lots of ways to achieve this. This one would hardly be the fastest in this case, but just for reference: you could use [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) as follows:

```
tmp = df.Medals_Won.str.extract(r'(?P<Gold_Winner>Gold)|(?P<Silver_Winner>Silver)|(?P<Bronze_Winner>Bronze)')

df[tmp.columns] = tmp
df = df.drop('Medals_Won', axis=1)
print(df)

   Teams  Year Gold_Winner Silver_Winner Bronze_Winner
0      A  2009        Gold           NaN           NaN
1      A  2010         NaN        Silver           NaN
2      A  2011         NaN        Silver           NaN
3      A  2012         NaN           NaN        Bronze
4      A  2013        Gold           NaN           NaN
5      B  2009         NaN           NaN        Bronze
6      B  2010        Gold           NaN           NaN
7      B  2011         NaN           NaN        Bronze
8      B  2012         NaN        Silver           NaN
9      B  2013         NaN        Silver           NaN
10     C  2009         NaN        Silver           NaN
11     C  2010         NaN           NaN        Bronze
12     C  2011        Gold           NaN           NaN
13     C  2012        Gold           NaN           NaN
14     C  2013         NaN           NaN        Bronze
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
>>>
tmp = pd.crosstab(df.index, df.pop('Medals_Won'))
out = df.join(tmp.columns.to_numpy()[None, :] * tmp.add_suffix('_Winner'))
print(out)


    Teams   Year    Bronze_Winner   Gold_Winner Silver_Winner
0   A       2009                    Gold    
1   A       2010                                Silver
2   A       2011                                Silver
3   A       2012    Bronze      
4   A       2013                    Gold    
5   B       2009    Bronze      
6   B       2010                    Gold    
7   B       2011    Bronze      
8   B       2012                                Silver
9   B       2013                                Silver
10  C       2009                                Silver
11  C       2010    Bronze      
12  C       2011                    Gold    
13  C       2012                    Gold    
14  C       2013    Bronze
```